# How to create logic to do value mapping in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this (except more columns and rows):

```
p_id
1
2
3
```

How do I create logic that is scalable to map certain values to certain numbers in the p_id column?

example df should look like:

```
p_id: 
a
b
c
```

in other words how do I make logic that says for every `1` in column `p_id`, change to `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you *could* use `Series.map` & pass in a dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': [1,2,3]})
df.p_id.map({1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'})
#output:
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: p_id, dtype: object
```

However, if your mapping an integer to an letter, you could use the `chr` function

```
# 97 is the ascii code for `a`
(df.p_id+96).map(chr)
#outputs:
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: p_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you very much